# In Android, how do I remove parts of text in a textview without using int?

Tags: android, textview

I'm receiving strings from AccessibilityService and it always returns text as "X:Y". I want to remove the : and X so that it only shows "Y", and vice versa ("X").

How would I do this? There is no de-append option in TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex seems like a simple solution for this.

```
String text = "asdfasf:qwertyqwert"; // get text in X:Y format
test = text.replaceAll(".*?:", ""); // remove "X:"
// contents of String are now "qwertyqwert"
```

Conversely, to remove :Y and keep X, do this:

```
String text = "asdfasf:qwertyqwert"; // get text in X:Y format
text = text.replaceAll(":.*", ""); // remove ":Y"
// contents of String are now "asdfasf"
```

Obviously you call getText() to get the String and setText() to set the result back to the TextView, but I figure you can probably do that part yourself.

Comment: This didn't seem to work. Not sure why.

notifHeader.setText(notif);


        if (notifHeader.getText().toString().contains(":")) {
            Log.i("ITDOES", "ITDOES");
            String fixed = notifHeader.getText().toString();
            fixed.replaceAll(":.*", "");
            notifHeader.setText(fixed);
        }

Comment: Hm, I thought it might be an error in my regex, but I tried it on RegexPlanet's interactive tester just now and it works fine.

Comment: Can you give an example of what the string looks like before you run replaceAll()?

Comment: The text is "1234: Message23" (sending a message via DDMS). I want to split them up.

Comment: Hm, try ": .*" or ": .*?", maybe? Though it really does look like your current code should work..

Comment: Not sure why. Even adding the string statically (I fetch it dynamically so it's always different but same layout X:Y) does not work with that method.

**EDIT** It should be "text = text.replaceAll". Thanks! :)

Comment: Ah, damn, I hate typos like that. I'll edit the answer so someone doesn't copy-paste the wrong code by mistake. :P

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the Split function that turns the string into an array where : is the delimiter

```
String[] textArray = text.Split(":")
```

textArray[0] is X

textArray[1] is Y

Comment: that : should probably be a ":", no?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a TextView.getText and substring the text you received and then setTextViewText again.